# how to sort order of custom blocks in sidebar in magento2

Tags: magento2, static-block, sidebar

I have used following code to insert custom blocks in sidebar.

but those are coming in the last of sidebar.i want first custom block-1 then layered navigation then custom block-2 etc.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>           
       <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
           <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="useourfinder" before="-">
               <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">useourfinder</argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
        </referenceContainer>        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
           <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="sandiego">
               <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sandiego</argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
        </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use after or before while adding block. Something like following...

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
```

For example, here I used **after** attribute to add that block after **footer_links** block.

Comment: i have tried.but its not working.i think issue with sidebar.additional container.

Comment: If you have updated code, paste here by editing question

Comment: before="-" means it should come before all blocks. check above code i also used before tag.

Comment: Okay. In before, try to give block name instead of -

Answer (score 1):

below code is working fine.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
    * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <move element="page.main.title" destination="main.columns.grid-main" before="-"/>
           <!--<move element="category.view.container" destination="main.columns.grid-main" after="page.main.title"/>-->
           <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main">
               <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="useourfinder" before="-">
                   <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">useourfinder</argument>
                   </arguments>
               </block>
            </referenceContainer>        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
               <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="sandiego">
                   <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sandiego</argument>
                   </arguments>
               </block>
            </referenceContainer>
       </body>
    </page>
```